# Elixir - Multiple expressions on same line - Compiler error when using do: syntax in function definition

Tags: elixir

In Elixir, multiple expressions can be delimited by semicolon (`;`).

Elixir complains in below function definition

```
defmodule Module2 do
    def func([c], n), do: IO.inspect(c); c + n
end
```

with error

```
** (CompileError) hello.exs:2: undefined function c/0
    (stdlib) lists.erl:1352: :lists.mapfoldl/3
    (stdlib) lists.erl:1352: :lists.mapfoldl/3
    (stdlib) lists.erl:1353: :lists.mapfoldl/3
```

However, Elixir is happy with below syntax.

```
defmodule Module1 do
    def func([c], n) do 
        IO.inspect(c); c + n
    end
end
```

I am not sure why one works over the other - as far as I understand both styles of function definition are equivalent.

---

Complete code below for reference

```
defmodule Module1 do
    def func([c], n) do 
        IO.inspect(c); c + n
    end
end
defmodule Module2 do
    def func([c], n), do: IO.inspect(c); c + n
end

Module1.func('r', 13)
Module2.func('r', 13)
```

Comment: check this [link](http://elixir-lang.org/crash-course.html#delimiters) in the delimiters part

Comment: I have seen it.  `;` seems to works in one style of definition and it does not work in other.  Both styles work fine if I get rid of `IO.inspect(c);`

Comment: one liners are supposed to be a single statement

Comment: #protip `IO.inspect/1` returns the given argument. This is very useful for inspecting an existing code so you could have written: `def func([c], n), do: IO.inspect(c) + n`

Comment: @JoséValim Thanks, Only the creator of language could have given that #protip.  By the way, will we ever use such code in production? In my code, I was using `IO.inspect` for debugging and was gonna get rid of it when function did what it meant to do.

Comment: I don't expect you to use in production, it was just a tip to aid debugging.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you really must do this, you will need to use parentheses:

```
defmodule Module2 do
  def func([c], n), do: (IO.inspect(c); c + n)
end
```

The problem with the original is the precedence of `;` vs function/macro calls, because of which it is parsed like this:

```
defmodule Module2 do
  (def func([c], n), do: IO.inspect(c)); c + n
end
```

You can verify that this gives the exact same error you mention - the compiler naturally complains because you're trying to use `c` outside of the context of the function.